# How to rename elements of an array of structs in Spark DataFrame API

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have an UDF which returns an array of tuples:

```
val df = spark.range(1).toDF("i")

val myUDF = udf((l:Long) => {
 Seq((1,2)) 
})

df.withColumn("udf_result",myUDF($"i"))
  .printSchema
```

gives

```
root
 |-- i: long (nullable = false)
 |-- test: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- _1: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- _2: integer (nullable = false)
```

I want to rename the elements of the struct to something meaningful instead of `_1` and `_2`, how can this be achieved? Note that I'm aware that returning a Seq of case-classes would let me allow to give proper field names, but using Spark-Notebook (REPL) with Yarn we have many issues using case classes, so I'm looking for a solution **without case-classes**.

I'm using Spark 2 but with untyped DataFrames, the solution should also be applicable for Spark 1.6

Comment: Duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39781222/renaming-nested-elements-in-scala-spark-dataframe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to cast the output of the udf. E.g. to rename the structfields to `x` and `y`, you can do:

type-safe:

```
val schema = ArrayType(
  StructType(
    Array(
      StructField("x",IntegerType),
      StructField("y",IntegerType)
    )
  )
)

df.withColumn("udf_result",myUDF($"i").cast(schema))
```

or unsafe, but shorter using  string-argument to `cast`

```
df.withColumn("udf_result",myUDF($"i").cast("array<struct<x:int,y:int>>"))
```

both will give the schema

```
root
 |-- i: long (nullable = false)
 |-- udf_result: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- x: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- y: integer (nullable = true)
```