# Strange behavior when casting array of structs in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, casting

I'm encountering a strange behavior using spark 2.1.1 and scala 2.11.8:

```
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(
  (1,Seq(("a","b"))),
  (2,Seq(("c","d")))
).toDF("id","data")

df.show(false)
df.printSchema()

+---+-------+
|id |data   |
+---+-------+
|1  |[[a,b]]|
|2  |[[c,d]]|
+---+-------+

root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- data: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- _1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _2: string (nullable = true)
```

Now I want to rename my struct fields as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/39781382/1138523

```
df
  .select($"id",$"data".cast("array<struct<k:string,v:string>>"))
  .show()
```

Which results in the correct schema, but the content of the dataframe is now:

```
+---+-------+
| id|   data|
+---+-------+
|  1|[[c,d]]|
|  2|[[c,d]]|
+---+-------+
```

Both lines show now the same array. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: In spark 2.1.2 (and also spark 2.3.0) I get the expected output. I also get the expected output if I cache the dataframe:

```
val df = Seq(
   (1,Seq(("a","b"))),
   (2,Seq(("c","d")))
).toDF("id","data")
.cache
```

Comment: there is no problem when I tried in spark 2.1.1 and scala 2.11.8.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan strange, I could reproduce the bug at 3 different computers (windows and linux, as well as in intellij and spark-notebook)

Comment: Well I just tried in Intellij on Windows and there seems no problem at all.

Comment: @RaphaelRoth I got same issue as you on Ubuntu. Feel like Ops now. After did some debug processes, I have some clues but still don't know the root cause.